# Dropzone.js/jQuery conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dropzone.js

I've got an app that has a Dropzone.js zone (two actually, on one page) alongside some custom jQuery. The custom jQuery (below) works fine.

```
function changeImage() {
  var self = $(this),
      src = this.value,
      thumbs = self.closest('.form-group').siblings('.selector_thumbnails');

 thumbs
     .find('img')
     .hide()
     .filter('#' + src)
     .show();
}

$('.thumbnail_selector')
    .change(changeImage)
    .trigger('change');
```

The corresponding HTML is as follows:

```
<div class='row form-group'>
  <div class='col-sm-2'></div>
  <div class='col-sm-4'>
    <%= f.input :cover_id, collection: @covers.reverse, as: :select, include_blank: true, input_html: { class: 'thumbnail_selector' } %>
    <div class='selector_thumbnails'>
      <% @covers.each do |cover| %>
        <%= image_tag(cover.cover(:cropped), id: cover.id, class: 'thumbnail') %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All that, though, prevents Dropzone from working. If I remove that code Dropzone works fine. What am I missing?

Here's my console (which is a Dropzone error, seemingly caused by the above JS):

[image: Console]

Comment: Are you sure `'#' + src` isn't evaluated to just `#`?

Comment: Not 100%, and I'm not too sure how to check. The functions works as wanted, though—and each image I'm switching to has an ID of `this.value` seen above.

Comment: Run `console.info('#' + src)` and look at the console output.

Comment: Yeah, correct: `#132` and similar.

Comment: Oh, goddammit, I figured it out. The include_blank in the select was breaking the jQuery. How embarrassing.

Comment: Ids cant start with a number. `#a123` would be valid, `#123` isn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the jQuery was trying to read the `.value` of the `include_blank: true` setting. So, solution:

```
function changeImage() {
  var self = $(this),
      src = this.value,
      thumbs = self.closest('.form-group').siblings('.selector_thumbnails');

  if (src) {
    thumbs.find('img').hide().filter('#' + src).show();
  } else {
    thumbs.find('img').hide();
  }
}
```

Done.